# How to rename an Ada constant defined in the private part

Tags: constants, private, ada, renaming

I want to rename a constant in the public part of a package (the original name is deprecated) that is defined in the private part. I tried this but GNAT says:

> full constant declaration appears too late

```
package Sample is

  type The_Type is private;
  My_Constant : constant The_Type;

  My_Renamed_Constant : The_Type;

private

  type The_Type is ...;
  My_Constant : constant The_Type := ...;

  My_Renamed_Constant : The_Type renames My_Constant;

end Sample;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a reason you want a rename instead of (say)
`function My_Renamed_Constant return The_Type;`
which simply returns My_Constant in the package body?

Functionally identical... and should inline if you're worried about speed.

Later in the deprecation process, make `My_Renamed_Constant` the constant and `My_Constant` the function instead. Then, when you think you're ready to retire it, have `function My_Constant` raise `Program_Error` or a custom exception indicating "using deprecated constant" to catch any usage you missed.

Comment: That might be a good solution if a renaming is impossible. I tried renaming the constant with the function, just like enumeration values can be renamed as function, but it didn't work. What I don't see clearly is the actual inlining. I think GNAT requires so much conditions, that it would probably not be applied.

Comment: I don't understand what "renaming the constant with the function" is, or what didn't work. As far as inlining/optimisation is concerned, Gnat is pretty smart and has the full range of gcc optimisations, plus Ada's clean semantics (unlike C "const") allow proper constant folding. So I would expect Gnat to streamline either of these answers nicely.

Comment: I mean: function My_Renamed_Constant return The_Type renames My_Constant; This was also rejected by the compiler, but for enumeration values it does work.

Comment: Oh no, I wouldn,t expect that to behave differently to a rename. I was suggesting a function body which returns the value.

Comment: And (Ada2012) the function body could be in the spec: `function My_Renamed_Constant return The_Type is (My_Constant);`.

Comment: I like the Ada-2012 version. Would you have to move it to the package body when you wanted it to `raise Program_Error;`?

Comment: No: `function My_Renamed_Constant return The_Type is (raise Program_Error);` compiles OK.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don’t need to use a renaming; would this do? (this may depend on exactly what the full declaration of `The_Type` is in your case)

```ada
package Sample is

  type The_Type is private;
  My_Constant : constant The_Type;

  My_Renamed_Constant : constant The_Type;

private

  type The_Type is new Integer;
  My_Constant : constant The_Type := 42;

  My_Renamed_Constant : constant The_Type := My_Constant;

end Sample;
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid that, since the private type is a record with one field depending on a size parameter (the package is actually generic). I wanted to avoid wasting memory and I suppose that this solutions uses different memory for each object. Or is the compiler so smart to share the memory? I don't think so.